# Updating Heroku App to Java 8

Tags: java, heroku, playframework, java-8

I have a `Play 2.2` app I'm using with Java 8 that I'm having trouble getting to work. The code compiles locally for me using OpenJDK 1.8, but when I try and push the code to Heroku, I get the following error, which was the error I was getting earlier locally when I was running on OpenJDK 1.7 with lambdas by accident.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown constant: 18
```

I set `system.properties` to use Java 1.8 and I know that's working because it's starting up with the following text:

```
Play 2.x - Java app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8...done
```

Is there something I'm forgetting to do to update to Java 8?
I tried updating the PATH as well as specified [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/add-java-version-to-an-existing-maven-app) but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Unknown constant: 18` most probably refers to [`CONSTANT_InvokeDynamic`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4) tag in the class file’s constant pool which has the value `18`. This can’t be a JDK issue as even Java 7 understands that tag.

So it is an indicator for a byte code manipulation tool running in your runtime not understanding newer class files (but trying to process them despite the unknown version number). That worked with Java 7 as the `invokedynamic` feature exists but is not used with ordinary Java 7 class files (i.e. produced by `javac`).

Since you knew if you used bytecode manipulation by yourself, it must be part of a framework, i.e. you named heroku and the playframework. So you problem is not about updating the JDK but updating the frameworks to Java-8-aware versions, if such versions already exist.

Comment: thanks @Holger, turns out Heroku doesn't completely support Java 8 yet, so I'm in the process of downgrading back to Java 7.

Comment: this was an issue I had with heroku and java 8 as well using play 2.2.x. I fixed the problem by changing the sbt version in build.properties from 0.13.0 to 0.13.1. Might work for you as well

Answer (score 2):

As an add-on to Holger's response, here's what Heroku support had to say:

Hi,

Java 8 is still on an old pre-release due to delays on a linux distribution of OpenJDK. You can track the status of JDK 8 here:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common/issues/10#issuecomment-38006175