# Spring 4 and Java 8 Invalid byte tag exception

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, java-8

I am trying to run a simple JUnit test using Spring and Java 8 JDK:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext.xml"})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class UserServicesTest{

  @Test
  public void testJava8() {
    Set<String> strings = new HashSet<>();
    strings.add("a");
    strings.add("b");
    strings.add("c");
    strings.stream().filter(a -> a.equals("a")).forEach(p -> p.toString());
  }
```

And I get this runtime error on startup:

```
org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 18
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:133)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:45)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:186)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:131)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.NonCachingClassLoaderRepository.loadJavaClass(NonCachingClassLoaderRepository.java:262)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.NonCachingClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(NonCachingClassLoaderRepository.java:242)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.NonCachingClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(NonCachingClassLoaderRepository.java:249)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.Java15AnnotationFinder.getAnnotations(Java15AnnotationFinder.java:202)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionBasedResolvedMemberImpl.unpackAnnotations(ReflectionBasedResolvedMemberImpl.java:211)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionBasedResolvedMemberImpl.hasAnnotation(ReflectionBasedResolvedMemberImpl.java:163)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ExactAnnotationTypePattern.matches(ExactAnnotationTypePattern.java:109)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ExactAnnotationTypePattern.matches(ExactAnnotationTypePattern.java:96)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AnnotationPointcut.matchInternal(AnnotationPointcut.java:156)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.Pointcut.match(Pointcut.java:137)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.getShadowMatch(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:239)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:105)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.internal.tools.PointcutExpressionImpl.matchesMethodExecution(PointcutExpressionImpl.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getShadowMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:404)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.matches(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:271)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:224)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:262)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:294)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:376)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:421)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1558)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:398)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I am using those aop libraries:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using AspectJ CTW? There appears to be an issue with the bytecode (AIUI, AspectJ has for a while produced some technically non-compliant code that the existing VMs accepted).

Comment: Same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/23622426/2711488

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You need `aspectJ` 1.8 to get Java 8 support.

Comment: We're on Spring 3.1.3.RELEASE and I was dabbling with JDK8.45 and this didn't fix it.  (I bumped aspectjrt to 1.8.5.)  FYI.

Comment: Spring 3.1.3 was released in December 2012! Java8 was not even available at that time...

Comment: I'm aware of that.  I was simply adding information.

Comment: This worked for me with Spring "3.1.2.RELEASE" (modified to work with Java 8). I bumped both "aspectjrt" and "aspectjweaver" from 1.6.5 to 1.9.2.

Comment: FTR, Spring 3.1 is EOL and does not support Java 8 officially.