# Mvn clean install tomcat7:deploy fails with "invalid byte tag in constant pool"

Tags: maven, tomcat7, aspectj-maven-plugin

Every time that I run mvn clean install tomcat7:deploy in the command prompt, it fails. When I open the generated log file, it says that there is an invalid byte tag in constant pool. The file that it specifies is java/lang/CharSequence.class.

Here is the log:

```
---- AspectJ Properties ---
AspectJ Compiler 1.6.9.RC3 built on Wednesday Jun 30, 2010 at 15:46:30 GMT
---- Dump Properties ---
Dump file: ajcore.20141116.131622.157.txt
Dump reason: org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException
Dump on exception: true
Dump at exit condition: abort
---- Exception Information ---
org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: File: 'java/lang    /CharSequence.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:192)
at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:131)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:412)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:373)
at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:452)
at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:298)
at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:211)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:95)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:41)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureGenericSignatureUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:807)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.getDeclaredInterfaces(BcelObjectType.java:255)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredInterfaces(ReferenceType.java:625)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getDirectSupertypes(ResolvedType.java:76)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.collectInterTypeMungers(ResolvedType.java:1390)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getInterTypeMungersIncludingSupers(ResolvedType.java:1371)
at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.checkInterTypeMungers(ResolvedType.java:1442)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.weaveInterTypeDeclarations(AjLookupEnvironment.java:791)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.weaveInterTypeDeclarations(AjLookupEnvironment.java:636)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(AjLookupEnvironment.java:1346)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.createBinaryTypeFrom(LookupEnvironment.java:599)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.accept(Compiler.java:276)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:113)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:133)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveTypesFor(BinaryTypeBinding.java:974)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.methodsBase(BinaryTypeBinding.java:957)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.methods(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1116)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Annotation.resolveType(Annotation.java:243)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.ASTNode.resolveAnnotations(ASTNode.java:594)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.isAspect(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:649)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.containsAnAspect(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:607)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.afterDietParsing(AjPipeliningCompilerAdapter.java:206)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.CompilerAdapter.ajc$afterReturning$org_aspectj_ajdt_internal_compiler_CompilerAdapter$4$2cef295e(CompilerAdapter.aj:93)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:358)
at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:371)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performCompilation(AjBuildManager.java:1022)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:268)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:181)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:112)
at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:363)
at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.runMain(Main.java:240)
at org.codehaus.mojo.aspectj.AbstractAjcCompiler.execute(AbstractAjcCompiler.java:360)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
---- System Properties ---
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path=c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\bin
java.vm.version=25.11-b03
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
guice.disable.misplaced.annotation.check=true
path.separator=;
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
user.country=US
user.script=
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
sun.os.patch.level=
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir=C:\Users\phill_000\Documents\Bingocise\Server\bingocise
java.runtime.version=1.8.0_11-b12
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs=c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\endorsed
os.arch=amd64
java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\PHILL_~1\AppData\Local\Temp\
line.separator=

java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
user.variant=
os.name=Windows 8.1
classworlds.conf=C:\devtools\maven\bin\..\bin\m2.conf
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
java.library.path=c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:    \WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;c:\users\phill_000\development\Android\sdk\tools;c:\users\phill_000\development\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Ant\bin;C:\Ant\bin\ant.bat;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\devtools\maven\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.2 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.2 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5.2 & MySQL Utilities 1.5.2 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\bin;C:\Users\phill_000\AppData\Roaming\npm;c:\users\phill_000\development\Android\sdk\tools;c:\users\phill_000\development\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Ant\bin;C:\Ant\bin\ant.bat;.
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version=52.0
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
os.version=6.3
user.home=C:\Users\phill_000
user.timezone=America/Chicago
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
file.encoding=Cp1252
java.specification.version=1.8
java.class.path=C:\devtools\maven\bin\..\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.1.jar
user.name=phill_000
java.vm.specification.version=1.8
sun.java.command=org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher clean install     tomcat7:deploy
java.home=c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre
sun.arch.data.model=64
user.language=en
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.version=1.8.0_11
java.ext.dirs=c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\ext;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\lib\ext
sun.boot.class.path=c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\resources.jar;c:\program     files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\rt.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11        \jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\jsse.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\jce.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\charsets.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\lib\jfr.jar;c:\program files\java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\classes
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
sun.stderr.encoding=cp437
maven.home=C:\devtools\maven\bin\..
file.separator=\
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.stdout.encoding=cp437
sun.desktop=windows
sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
---- Command Line ---
-outxml
-source
1.6
-target
1.6
-classpath
C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\antlr\antlr\2.7.6\antlr-2.7.6.jar;C:\Users\phill_000    \.m2\repository\aopalliance\aopalliance\1.0\aopalliance-1.0.jar;C:\Usersv    \phill_000\.m2\repository\asm\asm\3.1\asm-3.1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\cglib\cglib\2.2\cglib-2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\com\google\code\geocoder-java\geocoder-java\0.15\geocoder-java-0.15.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\com\google\code\gson\gson\1.7.2\gson-1.7.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\r08\guava-r08.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\com\itextpdf\itextpdf\5.3.1\itextpdf-5.3.1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\com\itextpdf\tool\xmlworker\1.1.5\xmlworker-1.1.5.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\com\sun\faces\jsf-api\2.2.7\jsf-api-2.2.7.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\com\sun\faces\jsf-impl\2.2.7\jsf-impl-2.2.7.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\commons-beanutils\commons-beanutils\1.8.0\commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.3\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.1\commons-collections-3.1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\20030825.184428\commons-dbcp-20030825.184428.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\commons-digester\commons-digester\2.0\commons-digester-2.0.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\commons-httpclient\commons-httpclient\3.1\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\commons-io\commons-io\1.3.1\commons-io-1.3.1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.4\commons-lang-2.4.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\commons-pool\commons-pool\20030825.183949\commons-pool-20030825.183949.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\dom4j\dom4j\1.6.1\dom4j-1.6.1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\javassist\javassist\3.9.0.GA\javassist-3.9.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\javax\activation\activation\1.1\activation-1.1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\javax\inject\javax.inject\1\javax.inject-1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\javax\mail\mail\1.4\mail-1.4.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\servlet-api\2.5\servlet-api-2.5.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jsp\jsp-api\2.1\jsp-api-2.1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\javax\transaction\jta\1.1\jta-1.1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\jboss\javassist\3.7.ga\javassist-3.7.ga.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.7\junit-4.7.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.16\log4j-1.2.16.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.16\mysql-connector-java-5.1.16.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\ognl\ognl\2.7.3\ognl-2.7.3.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\opensymphony\ognl\2.6.11\ognl-2.6.11.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr-runtime\3.3\antlr-runtime-3.3.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\antlr\stringtemplate\4.0.2\stringtemplate-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-api\2.2.2\tiles-api-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-compat\2.2.2\tiles-compat-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-core\2.2.2\tiles-core-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-el\2.2.2\tiles-el-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-extras\2.2.2\tiles-extras-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-freemarker\2.2.2\tiles-freemarker-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-jsp\2.2.2\tiles-jsp-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-mvel\2.2.2\tiles-mvel-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-ognl\2.2.2\tiles-ognl-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-servlet\2.2.2\tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-servlet-wildcard\2.2.2\tiles-servlet-wildcard-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-template\2.2.2\tiles-template-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\tiles\tiles-velocity\2.2.2\tiles-velocity-2.2.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\velocity\velocity\1.6.2\velocity-1.6.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\apache\velocity\velocity-tools\2.0\velocity-tools-2.0.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjrt\1.6.9\aspectjrt-1.6.9.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.6.11\aspectjweaver-1.6.11.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\atmosphere\atmosphere-annotations\2.1.7\atmosphere-annotations-2.1.7.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\atmosphere\atmosphere-compat-tomcat\2.0.1\atmosphere-compat-tomcat-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\atmosphere\atmosphere-compat-tomcat7\2.0.1\atmosphere-compat-tomcat7-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\atmosphere\atmosphere-runtime\2.1.7\atmosphere-runtime-2.1.7.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk16\1.46\bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-core-asl\1.9.13\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\codehaus\jackson\jackson-mapper-asl\1.9.13\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\freemarker\freemarker\2.3.15\freemarker-2.3.15.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\ejb3-persistence\1.0.2.GA\ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-annotations\3.4.0.GA\hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-commons-annotations\3.1.0.GA\hibernate-commons-annotations-3.1.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-core\3.3.0.SP1\hibernate-core-3.3.0.SP1.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\hibernate-entitymanager\3.4.0.GA\hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\jasypt\jasypt\1.9.0\jasypt-1.9.0.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\jasypt\jasypt-hibernate3\1.9.0\jasypt-hibernate3-1.9.0.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\jasypt\jasypt-spring31\1.9.0\jasypt-spring31-1.9.0.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\jsoup\jsoup\1.7.2\jsoup-1.7.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\mvel\mvel2\2.0.11\mvel2-2.0.11.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\primefaces\primefaces\5.0\primefaces-5.0.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\primefaces\extensions\all-themes\1.0.7\all-themes-1.0.7.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\primefaces\themes\all-themes\1.0.10\all-themes-1.0.10.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\quartz-scheduler\quartz\1.8.5\quartz-1.8.5.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\quartz-scheduler\quartz-jboss\1.8.5\quartz-jboss-1.8.5.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\quartz-scheduler\quartz-oracle\1.8.5\quartz-oracle-1.8.5.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\quartz-scheduler\quartz-weblogic\1.8.5\quartz-weblogic-1.8.5.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\reflections\reflections\0.9.5\reflections-0.9.5.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jcl-over-slf4j\1.5.10\jcl-over-slf4j-1.5.10.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\1.5.10\slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12\1.5.10\slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-context-support-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-expression-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-jdbc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-orm-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-oxm\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-oxm-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-test\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-test-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc-portlet\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\ldap\spring-ldap-core\1.3.2.RELEASE\spring-ldap-core-1.3.2.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-acl\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-security-acl-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-security-config-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-security-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-ldap\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-security-ldap-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-taglibs\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-security-taglibs-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\3.2.3.RELEASE\spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\webflow\spring-binding\2.4.0.RELEASE\spring-binding-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\webflow\spring-faces\2.4.0.RELEASE\spring-faces-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\webflow\spring-js\2.4.0.RELEASE\spring-js-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\webflow\spring-js-resources\2.4.0.RELEASE\spring-js-resources-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\springframework\webflow\spring-webflow\2.4.0.RELEASE\spring-webflow-2.4.0.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\org\tuckey\urlrewritefilter\4.0.3\urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\oro\oro\2.0.8\oro-2.0.8.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\taglibs\standard\1.1.2\standard-1.1.2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\.m2\repository\xml-apis\xml-apis\1.0.b2\xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar;C:\Users\phill_000\Documents\Bingocise\Server\bingocise\target\classes
-d
C:\Users\phill_000\Documents\Bingocise\Server\bingocise\target\classes
```

EDIT:These are the dependencies related to org.aspectj

```
<org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you post the version of your `org.aspectj` dependencies as specified in your pom.xml? If you are using Java 8, you need aspectj 1.8.

Comment: Maybe [Tomcat 7 - Servlet 3.0: Invalid byte tag in constant pool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751920/tomcat-7-servlet-3-0-invalid-byte-tag-in-constant-pool) or [Invalid byte tag in constant pool - Tomcat7, .war, JDK incompatibilty?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23484098/invalid-byte-tag-in-constant-pool-tomcat7-war-jdk-incompatibilty) helps.

Comment: I changed the org.aspectj version to 1.8. Now I'm getting a MojoFailureException. It does not print a log when it completes.

I have already viewed those posts, but they did not fix the issue.

Comment: ou need aspectJ 1.8 to get Java 8 support. Refer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801950/spring-4-and-java-8-invalid-byte-tag-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801950/spring-4-and-java-8-invalid-byte-tag-exception)

Answer (score 6):

I got the following error when I used aspectj-maven-plugin version 1.2 and version 1.6.1 for the aspectj dependencies with java 1.6.

```
[ERROR] Internal compiler error
org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: File: 'java/lang/CharSequence.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 18
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:192)
    at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:131)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:323)
    at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:277)
```

To fix this issue, I upgraded aspectj-maven-plugin to version 1.8 and version 1.8.7 for other aspectj dependencies. Here's my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.7</aspectj.version>
    <compiler.version>1.6</compiler.version>
</properties>

<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <configuration>
            <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
            <source>${compiler.version}</source>
            <target>${compiler.version}</target>
            <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
            <complianceLevel>${compiler.version}</complianceLevel>
            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            <verbose>false</verbose>
            <aspectLibraries>
                <aspectLibrary>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                </aspectLibrary>
            </aspectLibraries>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile</goal>
                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    ...
</plugins>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this error when building a project with Java 8 and AspectJ version 1.6.11, which as it turned out are incompatible.

**Solution**: Try to downgrade Java compiler to JDK 7 or upgrade AspectJ dependecies to 1.8+

Look for the following artifacts related to AspectJ in your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies have conflicts

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
     <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
     <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
   <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

remove the `aspectjweaver` dependency and run