# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.3.1:compile (default) on project greenhouse: Compiler errors:

Tags: java, maven, aspectj-maven-plugin

I have done all the researches I can online to solve this problem but I still cannot figure it out. Could anyone help me solve this? I don't even know what is happening as I am new to programming. Let me know if you need any code else I will edit the question to attach them. Thank you!

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.3.1:compile (default) on project greenhouse: Compiler errors:
[ERROR] error at (no source information available)
[ERROR] D:\BaiduYunDownload\Workspace\MvcExample\greenhouse\src\main\java\org\springframework\templating\StringTemplateLoader.java:0::0 Internal compiler error
[ERROR] org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: File: 'java/lang/CharSequence.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:192)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:131)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:424)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:376)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:467)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:308)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:218)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:97)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:41)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureGenericSignatureUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:810)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.getDeclaredInterfaces(BcelObjectType.java:257)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredInterfaces(ReferenceType.java:624)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getDirectSupertypes(ResolvedType.java:76)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.TypePattern.matchesSubtypes(TypePattern.java:178)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ExactTypePattern.matchesSubtypes(ExactTypePattern.java:74)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.TypePattern.matchesStatically(TypePattern.java:130)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.AndTypePattern.matchesStatically(AndTypePattern.java:62)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.DeclareParents.match(DeclareParents.java:63)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.DeclareParents.findMatchingNewParents(DeclareParents.java:358)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.doDeclareParents(AjLookupEnvironment.java:880)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.weaveInterTypeDeclarations(AjLookupEnvironment.java:730)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.weaveInterTypeDeclarations(AjLookupEnvironment.java:652)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.doPendingWeaves(AjLookupEnvironment.java:427)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.compiler.lookup.AjLookupEnvironment.completeTypeBindings(AjLookupEnvironment.java:213)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.internalBeginToCompile(Compiler.java:616)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.beginToCompile(Compiler.java:357)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:371)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performCompilation(AjBuildManager.java:1021)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.performBuild(AjBuildManager.java:268)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.internal.core.builder.AjBuildManager.batchBuild(AjBuildManager.java:181)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.doCommand(AjdtCommand.java:112)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.ajdt.ajc.AjdtCommand.runCommand(AjdtCommand.java:60)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.run(Main.java:371)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main.runMain(Main.java:248)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.mojo.aspectj.AbstractAjcCompiler.execute(AbstractAjcCompiler.java:370)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR] at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] abort ABORT -- (ClassFormatException) File: 'java/lang/CharSequence.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
[ERROR] File: 'java/lang/CharSequence.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
[ERROR] org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: File: 'java/lang/CharSequence.class': Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 15
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:192)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:131)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:424)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:376)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolveToReferenceType(World.java:467)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:308)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.World.resolve(World.java:218)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:97)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.classTypeSignature2TypeX(BcelGenericSignatureToTypeXConverter.java:41)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.ensureGenericSignatureUnpacked(BcelObjectType.java:810)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelObjectType.getDeclaredInterfaces(BcelObjectType.java:257)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ReferenceType.getDeclaredInterfaces(ReferenceType.java:624)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.ResolvedType.getDirectSupertypes(ResolvedType.java:76)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.TypePattern.matchesSubtypes(TypePattern.java:178)
[ERROR] at org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.ExactTypePattern.matchesSubtypes(ExactTypePattern.java:74)
```

My pom.xml:

```xml
<groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.oauth-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.integration-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.integration-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.integration-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-event</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.integration-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.mobile-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social.facebook-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social.facebook-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-linkedin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social.linkedin-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-tripit</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.social.tripit-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Remove once spring-aspects marks JPA as optional -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- CGLIB, only required and used for @Configuration usage -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.160</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For MapMaker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Http Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JavaMail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- String Template -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>stringtemplate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-impl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Tiles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-el</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- File Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- S3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jets3t</groupId>
            <artifactId>jets3t</artifactId>
            <!-- The next release of jets3t should have support for HttpComponents 
                4.1 and HttpClient 3.1 will be removed from the classpath -->
            <version>0.8.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Redis / Spring Key-Value -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                  <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test-mvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.test-mvc-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshot</id>
            <name>SpringSource Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For Spring releases -->
        <repository>
            <id>spring-repository</id>
            <name>SpringSource Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>SpringSource Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java-version}</source>
                    <target>${java-version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.1</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <!-- Note: Maven 2.0.9 or > required or these are ignored (MNG-2972) -->
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <outxml>true</outxml>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>write-active-profile-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Writes properties defined in current active profile(s) to application.properties, 
                                which is picked up by PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer in the classpath -->
                            <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/application.properties</outputFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Tomcat 7 Plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.t7mp</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-t7-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.9.M1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <contextPath>greenhouse</contextPath>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>publish</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <scp
                                    file="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}"
                                    todir="${publish.username}@${publish.host}:/tmp/greenhouse.war"
                                    keyfile="${publish.keyfile}" trust="true" />
                                <sshexec host="${publish.host}" username="${publish.username}"
                                    command="${publish.serverPath}/bin/tcruntime-ctl.sh stop"
                                    keyfile="${publish.keyfile}" trust="true" failonerror="false" />
                                <sshexec host="${publish.host}" username="${publish.username}"
                                    command="rm -rf ${publish.serverPath}/webapps/*" keyfile="${publish.keyfile}"
                                    trust="true" />
                                <sshexec host="${publish.host}" username="${publish.username}"
                                    command="mv /tmp/greenhouse.war ${publish.serverPath}/webapps/ROOT.war"
                                    keyfile="${publish.keyfile}" trust="true" />
                                <sshexec host="${publish.host}" username="${publish.username}"
                                    command="${publish.serverPath}/bin/tcruntime-ctl.sh start"
                                    keyfile="${publish.keyfile}" trust="true" />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-jsch</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useProjectReferences>false</useProjectReferences>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.codehaus.mojo
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            properties-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.0-alpha-2,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>
                                                write-active-profile-properties
                                            </goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute></execute>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- For testing against latest Spring snapshots -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshot</id>
            <name>SpringSource Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <!-- For Spring releases -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-repository</id>
            <name>SpringSource Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <!-- For developing against latest Spring milestones -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>SpringSource Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <!-- Temporary until we have a need to publish to a remote release repository -->
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>localPublish</id>
            <name>localPublish</name>
            <url>file://${user.home}/local-maven-publish-repository</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Comment: The problems is very likely in something you are declaring in your pom.xml. You should show it.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961098/mvn-clean-install-tomcat7deploy-fails-with-invalid-byte-tag-in-constant-pool

Comment: pom.xml uploaded!

Answer (score -4):

I have got same problem but then I found solution is to change line 29 in pom.xml to 1.8.7.
Then you should be able to compile without error.

Comment: when I count the posted code lines, in line 29 there is `</dependency>` you want to replace that? or am I counting wrong?

Comment: <!-- AspectJ -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
   <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
</dependency>
Sorry, I meant above lines.
And you can replace: ${org.aspectj-version} with 1.8.7

To be more clear, line 29 inside this link:
https://github.com/spring-projects/greenhouse/blob/master/pom.xml
It is the pom.xml of greenhouse project mentioned inside this post title.