# java 8 and lambda expression failed when try to use both on my local machine

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have started to use java 8, wrote a java class that have method that apply a function for each element of a list. I have a problem when run the test for this class, bellow it the method that generate this issue:

```
private static Source[] someMethod(List<URL> urls) throws IOException {

    Source[] array = urls.stream().map(xsd -> {
        try {
            return new StreamSource(xsd.openStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("message", e);
        }
    }).toArray(Source[] :: new);
 }
```

I get the following error:

```
org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not create class file from MyHelper.class
at org.reflections.scanners.AbstractScanner.scan(AbstractScanner.java:30)
at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:217)
at org.reflections.Reflections.scan(Reflections.java:166)
at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:94)
at org.reflections.maven.plugin.ReflectionsMojo.execute(ReflectionsMojo.java:148)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
Caused by: org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not create class file from MyHelper.class
at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.createClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:128)
at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOfCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:118)
at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.getOfCreateClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:26)
at org.reflections.scanners.AbstractScanner.scan(AbstractScanner.java:27)
... 25 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: **invalid constant type: 18**
at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.readOne(ConstPool.java:1090)
at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.read(ConstPool.java:1033)
at javassist.bytecode.ConstPool.<init>(ConstPool.java:149)
at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.read(ClassFile.java:737)
at javassist.bytecode.ClassFile.<init>(ClassFile.java:108)
at org.reflections.adapters.JavassistAdapter.createClassObject(JavassistAdapter.java:126)
```

do you have any clue about this issue ? it's something about java assit?

Comment: Java is not a dynamic language. you need to provide a proper type for `xsd`. I assume that is the problem. And can you provide `MyHelper` class

Comment: I have the same problem even if I specify the xsd varialbe type(URL xsd). From what I know java 8 can figure out what type of parameter is from the implementation of Function#apply method received by map method.

Comment: A **javassist** problem, maybe indeed in the conjunction with Java 8. The code itself works.

Comment: `javassist` library doesn't support Java 8. Check for new version.

Comment: @MladenUzelac The type of `xsd` is inferred.

Comment: i think the problem came from the fact of using reflection package from google. I have this package into mvn dependencies since I use from other task.

Comment: Yes, that's your problem. You need to upgrade it, if such an upgrade exists.

Comment: i checked and I use the last version of org.reflections. do you know why java assist use this package and not his internal package ?

Comment: @srncristea: you are reversing the responsibility. It is `javassist` which doesn’t support Java 8 and the question has to be why `org.reflections` uses `javassist`.

Comment: By the way that exception `invalid constant type: 18` suggests that this version of `javassist` doesn’t even support Java 7 correctly. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/23625762/2711488

Comment: seams that org.reflections(from google version 0.9.9) use inside as dependency org.javassist 3.1.8.2-GA(last version from github), I look again on the stacktrace and there is a warning, the code running correctly and if I make a debug, the debug process evaluate that lines that throw the warning.