# Why I am getting org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19

Tags: exception, java-8, tomcat8

**Java version:8**

**Tomcat version: 8.5.8**

I am getting below exception, however it is not impacting any functionality as such, but it is creating logs in catalina.out which it supposed to create in different file. Also how to eliminate this issue so that tomcat won't throw any exception and create logs file as expected.

**Exception I am getting**

```
25-Mar-2021 14:57:29.833 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [file:/home/diwakarb/apache-tomcat-8.5.8-VerifiedSMSCustomApp/webapps/VerifiedSMSCustomApp/WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.11.1.jar] for annotations
 org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Constant.readConstant(Constant.java:97)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.<init>(ConstantPool.java:54)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readConstantPool(ClassParser.java:174)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:83)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2053)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:2000)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1970)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1923)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1163)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

25-Mar-2021 14:57:33.784 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

**Logs I am getting in catalina**

```
 [INFO ] 2021-03-25 14:57:34.168 [localhost-startStop-1] ApplicationCommonLog - VERIFIED_SMS DBConnection : get initial context : initial context is org.apache.naming.NamingContext@f7b34df
[INFO ] 2021-03-25 14:57:34.175 [localhost-startStop-1] ApplicationCommonLog - CORE PROPERTIES ADDED SUCCESSFULLY
```

It should supposed to logs these logs in different file instead of catalina

**log4j2.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">/home/diwakarb/apache-tomcat-8.5.8-VerifiedSMSCustomApp/logs</Property>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p :- %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="commonLogger" fileName="${basePath}/common.log"
                     filePattern="${basePath}/common.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <RollingFile name="errorLogger" fileName="${basePath}/error.log"
                     filePattern="${basePath}/error.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <AsyncLogger name="ApplicationCommanLog" level="debug" additivity="false" includeLocation="true">
            <appender-ref ref="commonLogger" level="debug"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <AsyncLogger name="ApplicationErrorLog" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="errorLogger" level="debug"/>
        </AsyncLogger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.acl</groupId>
    <artifactId>VerifiedSMSCustomApp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <verifiedsms.client.version>1.2</verifiedsms.client.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>in-project</id>
            <name>In Project Repo</name>
            <url>file:///${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- In-project Verified SMS dependencies. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vsmsagent</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib_verified_sms_client</artifactId>
            <version>${verifiedsms.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vsmsagent</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib_verified_sms_data_munging</artifactId>
            <version>${verifiedsms.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>vsmsagent</groupId>
            <artifactId>lib_verified_sms_hashing</artifactId>
            <version>${verifiedsms.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Standard dependencies. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>0.21.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>28.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-auth</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.crypto.tink</groupId>
            <artifactId>tink</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.58</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- For JDK 11 and above. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--  ACL newly added -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.10</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160212</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
            <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <finalName>VerifiedSMSCustomApp</finalName>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.xolstice.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>protobuf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <protocArtifact>com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.9.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</protocArtifact>
                    <pluginId>grpc-java</pluginId>
                    <pluginArtifact>io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.23.0:exe:${os.detected.classifier}</pluginArtifact>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-custom</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: This is similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23622426/2711488) which boils down to having a bytecode processing library not being up-to-date for the currently used class files. The difference is that constant pool entries of type 19 can only appear in module declarations, in other words, in code compiled for Java 9 or newer.

Comment: but I am compiling the same by using java 8, I have installed JDK 8 version.
What I can possibly do, I have tried to upgrade to tomcat version 10 as well, no success at all. in my pom.xml which dependency causing this is unable to find that.as there are lot of dependencies are there, how to troubleshoot the same.

Comment: I have focused too much on the “Invalid byte tag in constant pool: 19” error message of the question’s title. The log output even says literally “*Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [file:/home/diwakarb/apache-tomcat-8.5.8-VerifiedSMSCustomApp/webapps/VerifiedSMSCustomApp/ WEB-INF/lib/jackson-core-2.11.1.jar*”, so that’s the jar containing a module declaration.

Comment: that's what I am saying, even I noticed that jackson-core-2.11.1.jar but there is no maven dependency defined in pom.xml for this jar, why it is searching for this jar?
I have attached pom.xml as well.

Comment: thanks @Holger for your valuable time to assist me. :)

Answer (score 1):

I have done work around, not sure this is the right way or not, but it worked for me without impacting any functionality change.

In *catalina.properties* file, **tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip** section

I have added **jackson-*.jar** to ignore this dependency at run time as in my case it is searching for this dependency.